# curvature tensor of involutive distributions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

The Riemann curvature tensor is defined
$$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y \nabla_XZ - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z.$$

Is it possible to simplify above expression under assumption that $X,Y\in D$, where $D$ is an involutive (regular) distribution, namely
$$[X,Y]\in D$$

I did the obvious step but then I struggle
$$[X,Y]=\alpha X + \beta Y,$$
where $\alpha,\beta \in C^\infty(Q)$. Hence

$$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_Y \nabla_XZ - \alpha \nabla_XZ - \beta \nabla_YZ$$

Especially I'd like to simplify the condition for the manifold to be flat, i.e. the case $R=0$.
Any ideas?

What is the geometric interpretation of the relation between involutivity and flatness? Any interesting reference on that matter?

Cheers,

Comment: There is no relationship, unless you have a foliation of your big manifold by flat submanifolds. Think about foliating $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ by spheres centered at the origin.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Thanks, that gives me a new uderstanding of my problem. Does anyone consider a regular foliation of a manifold with integral manifolds that has zero curvature? Is there known  something special about this case? Any literature on that?

Comment: First problem is that $[X,Y]$ would be a combination of vectors in $D$, possibly different from $X$ or $Y$, as we have no assumptions on the rank of the distribution whatsoever. And there is a relation between flatness and the integrability of a distribution, but not on the manifold: $R=0$ if and only if the horizontal distribution $\mathcal{H}\hookrightarrow TM$ is involutive.